# React infinite loop caused by component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently in the process of learning react and have come across a problem has had me stuck for most of the day. I have two simple components. Once called IncidentsBoard which holds other components called Incidents.

The idea is that (using dummy data) the IncidentBoard will show incidents of car crashes on it. My code:

IncidentBoard:

```
import React from 'react';
import Incident from './Incidents';
import testData from './testdata';

class IncidentBoard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: testData.features,
            filtered: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {

        var filtered = this.state.data.filter( (incident, i) => {
            return incident.properties.event_type === 'Crash';
        })

        console.log(filtered);
        this.setState({filtered})   

    }   

    render() {
      return <div>
            {this.state.filtered.map((incident, i) => {
                return <Incident id={i} description="swagg" />
            })}
        </div>
    }
}
export default IncidentBoard;
```

Incident (which is currently mostly empty):

```
import React from 'react';

class Incident extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div><h1>test</h1></div>
    }

}

export default Incident;
```

When running this, it causes an infinite loop where componentWillMount() is run without end. I have also noticed that if I replace the Incident component in the render function in IncidentBoard that the error no longer happens.

EDIT: More code

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import IncidentBoard from './Incidents';

ReactDOM.render(
    <IncidentBoard />, document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

testData is a just a big JSON object.

Comment: Can the error be in the component where you use `IncidentBoard`?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a problem with `componentWillMount`, it shouldn't loop.

Comment: Here I tried to reproduce your problem, but everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/74080/

Comment: Everything looks good to me. The issue is probably caused by some of the other logic inside the `IncidentBoard` component. Please share more code.

Comment: How does `testData.features` look like?

Comment: If the json is very big. the main thread vl be stuck in that and vl never render  . try reducing the size of the json n try again